# How to add an input field with a date to the checkout page?

Tags: javascript, xml, php-7

I'm studying Magento2, downloaded the module https://github.com/ecomteck/module-delivery-date   and added it to the app / code / vendor / module-delivery-date folder

I cannot understand in which files and what needs to be changed in order to display my input and connect with the checkout module.
I hope for your help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install the module exactly as instructed on the vendor's page:

```
composer require ecomteck/module-delivery-date
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: yes, I saw the installation instructions. But to study Magento2, I was told to install in the directory app / code / :(  I know how to install, create a module, but I don't know how to insert new data from one module into another

Comment: the module itself should already do that. try executing the above comands **except** the composer one. maybe you added the module properly in app/code, but it's not yet recognized by Magento :)

Comment: hmm, I have it activated :(  sorry for my not correct english I'm communicating with you through a translator :)

Comment: I downloaded the module again and did the same setting for installation and it was displayed in the right place, only now without the date selection icon

Comment: glad you almost sorted it out :) check if the icon file has the proper permissions.

Comment: As I understand it, that icon forms some kind of  js file, but I don't know yet which one and how to check. Probably file delivery-date-block.js in ../view/frontend/web/js/view directory is responsible for the icon

Comment: but how to display I have no idea

Comment: And here is the error in the console when loading the page:
knockout.js: 3381 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "datetimepicker: function () {return true}"
Message: $ el.datetimepicker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can install this module in two ways:

> First Way

Create directory structure "**app/code/Ecomteck/DeliveryDate**"
Download all files from there [Github Module Link](https://github.com/ecomteck/module-delivery-date)
Upload all files inside the **DeliveryDate** directory
Then run the below commands on Magento root.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
**For production mode:**
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
**For developer mode:**
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

> Second Way

Install Module by Composer:
Run below commands on Magento root.

```
composer require ecomteck/module-delivery-date
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
**For production mode:**
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
**For developer mode:**
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```